# pgAdmin 4 only shows 2 tabs:Dashboard and Browser

Tags: pgadmin-4

recently I installed pgAdmin 4. It was working without any problems until yesterday when I opened it and was greeted with this screen.

[image: Faulty pgAdmin (Object tab has no options)]

Does anyone have possible solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to C:\Users\YOUR_USER_NAME\AppData\Roaming and delete pgAdmin folder.

It will clear all pgAdmin preferences and passwords and restore the default user interface.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the refresh button and select `Empty Cache and Hard Reload`

Open pgAdmin4 again & Check if that helps.

[image]